# removeChild causing error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that looks like this:

```
    <form id="donate_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.google.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="donate_custom_input" value="">
    </form>
```

I also have a button that, when pressed calls a function that adds 3 new inputs to it.
So after the button is pressed the form looks like this:

```
    <form id="donate_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.google.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="donate_custom_input" value="">
        <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="item_name_1" value="item1">
        <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="amount_1" value="5">
        <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    </form>
```

Now I'm trying to create a button that's capable of deleting the 3 inputs from the form.

So i wrote the following function:

```
function removeFromForm(id)
{
    var formChilds = form.children; //Get array of children elements

    //formChildrenOffset = the amount of children in the form before the 3 new elements were added, so 6
    for(var i = formChildrenOffset;i < formChilds.length;i++)
    {
        if(formChilds[i].dataset.formid == id) //once we found an element with formID equal to the id of the elements we want to delete
        {
            for(var j = i; j < i+3; j++) //run a loop 3 times, to remove the 3 elements
                form.removeChild(formChilds[j]); //this seems to cause the error when j is 1

            break; //no need to go through the rest of the elements, so break;
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is when i call the function it gives me the following error:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter        
   1 is not of type 'Node'.
       at removeFromForm (script.js:113)
       at RemoveFromCart (script.js:81)
       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (shop.php:1)
```

and the form ends up looking like this:

```
    <form id="donate_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="rspslegendx-facilitator@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.google.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="donate_custom_input" value="">
        <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="amount_1" value="5">
    </form>
```

So it seems that something is causing an error when it tries to remove the second element after the second loop.

I've been trying to figure out whats causing it for a while now, but i cant seem to figure it out. Maybe someone else can spot my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have this array `[a,b,c,d,e]`.  You want to remove `b,c,d` so you make a loop from 1 to 3 (the array indices of `b,c,d`) and remove index 1, then index 2, then index 3.  But when you remove index 1 your array becomes `[a,c,d,e]` So removing index 2 leaves `[a,c,e]` Then removing index 3 gives `error - there is no index 3`

To fix this either subtract 1 from the iterator you're using when you remove an element, or iterate the array backwards, or keep removing the same array index j times.

Anyway here's more concise way to remove the form fields (I made the 3 to be removed text fields so it's obvious they're gone)

```js
function removeFromForm(id) {
  var f = document.querySelector("#donate_form");
  var inps = f.querySelectorAll("input[data-formid='" + id + "']");
  for (var i=inps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    f.removeChild(inps[i]);
  }
}
removeFromForm(1);
```

```html
    <form id="donate_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.google.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="donate_custom_input" value="">
        <input type="text" data-formid="1" name="item_name_1" value="item1">
        <input type="text" data-formid="1" name="amount_1" value="5">
        <input type="text" data-formid="1" name="quantity_1" value="1">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `form.removeChild(formChilds[j]);` to `form.removeChild(formChilds[i]);`. The problem is when you are deleting the form elements your array length is changing and resulting in exception.

```js
function removeFromForm(id)
{
  var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
    var formChilds = form.children; //Get array of children elements

    //formChildrenOffset = the amount of children in the form before the 3 new elements were added, so 6
    for(var i = 6;i < formChilds.length;i++)
    {
        if(formChilds[i].dataset.formid == id) //once we found an element with formID equal to the id of the elements we want to delete
        {
            for(var j = i; j < i+3; j++) //run a loop 3 times, to remove the 3 elements
                form.removeChild(formChilds[i]); //this seems to cause the error when j is 1

            break; //no need to go through the rest of the elements, so break;
        }
    }

}
removeFromForm(1);
```

```html
<form id="donate_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.google.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" id="donate_custom_input" value="">
  <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="item_name_1" value="item1">
  <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="amount_1" value="5">
  <input type="hidden" data-formid="1" name="quantity_1" value="1">
</form>
```